# How to add multiple values under the same key for FireBase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I add multiple values for the same key in Firebase? When I do the following to add data to my database, the objects are just replacing each other.

```
    Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<>();
    taskMap.put("age", "12");
    taskMap.put("gender", "male");
    taskMap.put("age", "45");
    taskMap.put("gender", "female");
    reference.setValue(taskMap);
```

The data in Firebase only displayed age 45, and gender female. It overrode the age 12 and gender male. How do I have both?

Comment: Can you explain more about the context of what you are trying to do? A `Map` is like a list of key-value pairs, where the keys are unique and have 1 single value. Each time you write a value to a new key, like `taskMap.put("age", "45");`, it will overwrite whatever was there before.

Comment: you use a pojo class for get actual data your Map syntax will apply like:
  Map<String,Pojo> taskMap = new HashMap<>();
    taskMap.put("1",new Pojo("gender","age"));
     taskMap.put("2",new Pojo("gender","age"));
    reference.setValue(taskMap);

Comment: I think you are trying to save multiple users data. In that case, you can create separate map/pojo objects for each user and push it to 'users' node. Please refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: @NagarajN You are right. Silly mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To update a subset of the existing properties or to add new ones, use `updateChildren()`:

```
Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<>();
taskMap.put("age", "12");
taskMap.put("gender", "male");
taskMap.put("age", "45");
taskMap.put("gender", "female");
reference.updateChildren(taskMap);
```

Also see the [documentation for updating specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).